# How do I add a category to a MediaWiki Page?

Tags: mediawiki

I tried editing the page, but I couldn't see an option to edit the category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your page

```
[[Category:NAME]]
```

Answer (score 0):

After you add the category with [[Category:name]] you should follow the link it creates. I usually add the wiki text:

```
<nowiki>[[category:name]]</nowiki>
```

to the Category page.